# Problema de encoding no composer

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, composer

Atualmente o meu arquivo do composer começou a apresentar alguns erros nas mensagens que parecem erros de encoding, alguém já passou por isso e sabe como resolver? Dei uma pesquisada pra ver se achava algo mas não encontrei nenhuma resposta a respeito disso.

Segue a imagem para mostrar como está vindo o restorno:

[image: erro de encoding no log do composer]

Alguém sabe como é possível resolver esse problema?

Comment: Qual seu sistema operacional? Outras ações no prompt não dão erro de encoding? Só acontece com o composer?

Comment: Estou usando windows 10 com o anniversary update, acontece apenas com o composer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema ocorre devido a última atualização do Windows 10 (Anniversary Update) que causou esse erro de encoding. Se usar o Powershell do cmd ficará tudo certo.
Então a melhor solução é aguardar uma nova atualização que corrija esse problema.